# Fetching data from service now using web services

Tags: servicenow

Out of these WebServices, which one is better to fetch the data and why?
* Rest Api
* Soap Api
* ODBC Driver

I heard ODBC approach is fast.

Answer (score 0):

ODBC is going to probably be fastest, just because of the slightly less "transactional" nature, and the lighter wrapper. For ease of use though, I prefer REST. It's also much more modular, easily implemented in both directions, easily modified, and easily adapted.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it would be true to say that ODBC is "faster" than SOAP or REST, but the ServiceNow ODBC driver is really just a wrapper around the SOAP API. The SQL statements you issue to ODBC essentially just get translated into SOAP requests, so the performance is just going to be comparable to the SOAP API.

REST is a more "modern" API with lower overhead (SOAP is passing around XML payloads which are going to have a larger storage footprint than REST in most circumstances). This is especially true for ServiceNow, where investment into rich REST API support is strong and more up to date.